# Android inflate from separate xml

Tags: android, inflate

How to inflate particular View from separate xml file. Is it possible? When I`m trying to set id of this View I just have an ResourceNotFoundException.
Maybe I need to set somehow the name of file?

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
FrameLayout ingredients_frame = (FrameLayout)inflater.inflate(R.id.ingredients_frame, null);
```

R.id.ingredients_frame located just in separate xml file.

Exception:

```
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060032 type #0x12 is not valid
```

ingredients_frame_layout.xml:

```
<FrameLayout 
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/ingredients_frame"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/expandable_second_layer_selector" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="......................................................................................................................................................................"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_orange"
                android:textSize="18dip"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ingredient_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/friends_total"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_orange"
                android:textSize="18dip" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ingredient_data"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_orange"
                android:textSize="18dip" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Post some code what have you tried..

Comment: Try this `LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this -

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ingredients_frame_layout, null);
```

And, the use of `View` class object you can identifiy other components which is in your layout. Ex, if you've one textView in your layout `example`

```
TextView tv = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText("Hello world");
```

Based on this, just identify your `FrameLayout` like this

```
FrameLayout ingredients_frame = (FrameLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.ingredients_frame);
```

Comment: But FrameLayout is parent View for all others. So I`m doing (FrameLayout)inflater.inflate(R.id.ingredients_frame, null). XMl code I `ve attached already.

Comment: @Stas Then, just try to give `(FrameLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.ingredients_frame_layout, null)` Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);
```

Do the above way instead of taking framelayout and than take your textviews like this

```
TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);

TextView txtTitle2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ingredient_name);

txtTitle.setText(yourtext);
```

Comment: Look at my code, please. Doesn`t it look like what you wrote? What I`m doing wrong?

Comment: I think FrameLayout- Have you taken framelayout in xml also? Can you post your xml code of ingredients_frame.

Answer (score 1):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
FrameLayout ingredients_frame = (FrameLayout)inflater.inflate(YOUR_LAYOUT, null);
```

The first parameter in inflate method is LAYOUT but not ID. Good Luck!